# How to fix the keyless key (replace the antenna) of Mistubishi Outlander?

Tags: pcb, identification, remote-control, pcb-antenna

Background story:

- I had a keyless keyfob for my Outlander, and lost it.
- I went to the service and they configured a new key for me.
- The serviceman told me that many times when the key falls the antenna gets broken, so we must take care.
- I found the old key, but it does not work anymore. (They changed the car code.)
- The new key fell (I promise it's not my fault.) Now the buttons aren't working and I can't start the car unless I put the key in its slot.

I would like to do the following:

1. Move the code from the new key to the old key.

OR

2. Move the antenna from the old key to the new one.

An image of the old key:

[image]

I believe it will be much easier to switch the antenna. Which of the parts in the image is the antenna?

Here is a better (similar) picture from [here:](https://www.joom.com/en/products/5f8e9c8b2c29c50106e3f6d3) (Those images are from the Internet, A post editor added them)

[image]

Comment: Identifying an antenna on a PCB is on-topic here, the rest of your car key concerns are not. Based on the blurry pic provided, I see no antenna at all, but clearly I'm missing something. I'd either expect a chip antenna or perhaps in case of 2.4GHz or such an integrated PCB antenna. Could you provide a better photo of the PCB and also of the opposite side?

Comment: The miscolored "copper" parts of the PCB suggests temperature problems, maybe a short somewhere. It looks like the solder mask burnt off or maybe this is caused by some chemical (why are the IC legs copper colored??). So I would suspect a whole lot more fundamental problems with this PCB and it may be beyond salvaging.

Comment: the antenna is the circle at the top under the battery.

Comment: Do any of the LEDs blink when you push a button?  Normally, an LED will blink when you push a button.  This is to let you know that the fob is working.   If no LED blinks, then something is wrong.  It would surprise me if the antenna breaks when you drop the fob.  I would tend to expect the crystal for the microcontroller to break.  If the crystal is broken then the LED won't blink when you press a button.  Press a button on both fobs.  See which one blinks.  I expect you will find that the broken one doesn't blink.

Comment: @JRE I didn't check yet the LED, but the car is working when the key is inside the slot, so it's strange for me, if something is not work.

Comment: Anyway the orange goo all over your original pic is likely the cause of your problems, not the antenna.

Comment: The car runs when the key is in the slot because there's a mechanical switch activated by the physical presence of the key - no electronics involved.  Push buttons, check for blinking.

Comment: I will check. But it's not physically connected to anything, it's a slot to put the key in case the battery is over https://i.redd.it/8bhuvxds4ez41.jpg

Comment: @lundin the old one was just lost, and then removed from the cars authorized keys. The orange stuff has no relation to it not operating the car.

Answer (score 1):

In the picture of your old keyfob, it clearly lists the large black box bottom left as COIL ANT. *This is the 3 antennas for keyless entry, which are in 3 different spacial directions*. There seems to be a pcb antenna for UHF transceiver but thats unlikely to break since its solid copper on the board.

The two PCBs are not identical so you may not be able to transfer the antenna from one to the other.

As an smd part, it may be difficult for you to unsolder and resolder without damaging the antenna or the other parts on the board.

Have you googled how to program your own key?

Comment: Hmm really? I thought that was a buzzer, but you are probably correct. I can't see any RF signal trace though...?

Comment: Also what's the long wide trace on the bottom with no vias going in a loop? In case it isn't a PCB antenna? That would be some mighty weird routing.

Comment: @Lundin it looks like a multilayer board. There's vias with a connection only to one side. Can't really say. As for the antenna it looks like https://www.murata.com/en-global/products/antenna/antennacoil/overview/lineup/rx SA-X20 a 8 pin triaxial rfid automotive ID style antenna.

Comment: Maybe they have multiple antennas depending on country/frequency band. Because the L1, L2, L3 and caps do look like matching components - what else would they be? They have nothing to do with the battery or the crystal. and I can't make any sense of the big trace at the bottom unless it's an antenna.

Comment: @lundin seems those are a pcb antenna for the uhf transceiver option for the pcf7952 ic. Which is separate from the keyless triaxial receiver antennas. The matching caps are the three by the IC and ic antenna.

Comment: I didn't googled how to program. It's a very good idea. I thought that I need special illegal machines for that... But now, since I already have a working fob.

Comment: @AminadavGlickshtein some cars just need a paired master physical key others are some special "open door press button lower window close door" for programming mode. Others require a special programmer. It varies.

Comment: The NXP part apparently comes with a 125kHz inductive receiver as well as a UHF radio. I found a product brief here: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/brochure/75017275.pdf

Comment: @lundin the 5100 ic

Comment: Since you only appear to misplace them get two working keys from the dealer, possible one or both of the ones you have. While you are looking for one use the other. I do not know about your vehicle but all of mine came with two keys and I purchased a third just in case.